# How can i display related items in detail page in reactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

I have the following code in index.js which dipslay all employee information from json file. --- codesandbox[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gates-2xkl7) ---

```
return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          value={this.state.input}
          type="text"
          onChange={e => this.onSearchTextChange(e.target.value)}
        />
        <List divided>
          {cardData.data.Table.map(results => (
              <div class="body">
                  <h3 className="title">{results.first_name}</h3>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                      {" "}
                      Department: {results.Department}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {/* row for Location cubicle Prof  */}

                  <Link
                    to={{ pathname: `/cards/${results.id}`, state: results }}
                    className={`card-wrapper restore-${results.id}`}
                  >
                    display
                  </Link>
                </div>
          ))}
        </List>
       </div>
    );
```

I also have details.js file which display selected employee detail information as follows

```
render() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const data = cardData.data.Table.find(item => item.id === id);
    return (
      // Card details compoment
      <div className="card-details">
        <h2>{data.first_name}</h2>
        <h2>{data.id}</h2>

        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: this.props.location.state
          }}
        >
          <button>Return to list</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
```

How can i display employees in the same department name in the selected record detail Page?.
I have data i have a data as shown below on employee 1001 detail page i would like to show `Id` and `first_name` of  employee with id 1003 because both in the same department

```
"data": {
    "Table": [
      {
        "id": "1001",
        "first_name": "Alez",
        "Department": "IT"
      },
      {
        "id": "1002",
        "first_name": "Baro",
        "Department": "Accounting"
      },
      {
        "id": "1003",
        "first_name": "Tata",
        "Department": "IT"
      },
```

Comment: Group by department?

Comment: @Kuku you want all employees of same department in one list?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar yes i will do use Carousel

Comment: use department as path parameter not employee Id.

Comment: @JuniusL. you don't get what i am wanted to accomplish i want the detail page to be the selected employee information by ID but i want to show employees related in the same page at the bottom of the page which share the sameDepartment or  same supervisor something like that, just like when you purchase item you see related items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter to filter by department in your details page, and only show eployees in that department.

```
const relatedTo = cardData.data.Table.filter(
  item => item.Department === data.Department && item.id !== data.id
);
```

in your Details.js render method change your code to the following.

```
render() {

  const id = this.props.match.params.id;
  const data = cardData.data.Table.find(item => item.id === id);

  const relatedTo = cardData.data.Table.filter(
    item => item.Department === data.Department && item.id !== data.id
  );

  return (
    // Card details compoment
    <div className="card-details">
      <h2>{data.first_name}</h2>
      <h2>{data.id}</h2>

      <h3>Works with: </h3>
      {relatedTo &&
        relatedTo.map(emp => (
          <div>
            <h4>{emp.first_name}</h4>
            <h4>{emp.id}</h4>
          </div>
        ))}

      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/",
          state: this.props.location.state
        }}
      >
        <button>Return to list</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks where can i  add it and display it?

Comment: in the details.js component render, I'll paste the code.

Comment: demo https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-poitras-nmxqu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: you are welcome and remember to add keys to your lists https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Junius can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315973/display-data-from-api